# Output referenced entity in correct language

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

The following code outputs referenced entities in the original language they were created.

```
{% for story in node.field_stories %}
  {{ story.entity.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want it to render in the current language (translation) instead. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use the raw field value, use the render array of the field instead:

```
{{ content.field_stories }}
```

This will automatically use the correct language.

NOT RECOMMENDED:
If you have to go the custom, raw value route you can do something like

```
{% for story in node.field_stories %}
  {% if story.entity.hasTranslation('iso2_langcode') %}
    {{ story.entity.getTranslation('iso2_langcode').label }}
  {% else %}
    {# fallback default lang #}
    {{ story.entity.label }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - works perfectly!